# How can I make this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, grids

I have a problem with this graphic.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    grid={major},clip=false,grid style={dashed},
    y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
    ytick={2,4},
    xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.5, ymax=4,ymin=-0.5,
    ylabel={$f_{(t)}$}, xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel style={at={(axis cs:0,4.2)}}, 
    xlabel style={at={(axis cs:4.75,0)}}]
    \draw[ultra thick,blue](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:1,2)--(axis cs:1,0)--(axis cs:2,0);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,dashed](axis cs:2,0)--(axis cs:3,2)--(axis cs:3,0)--(axis cs:4,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I want to make the graph on the right. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please find a more descriptive title for your post? What do you mean by "this graphic"?

Comment: Yes, my problem it's that i don't know how to do the graph on the right

Comment: The reason I ask this is because this site represents a resource to future visitors and with a title like "How to draw this graph" it won't receive any future attention since the title or post content doesn't include any detail that would be found in a search. So, in the future, think about asking *specific* questions with enough detail to avoid this type of phrasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has room for improvements, but as a quick hack. The code has comments where I changed things, ask if there is anything that requires further explanation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    grid={both}, % changed
    clip=false,
    grid style={solid}, %changed
    y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
    x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
    ytick={0,2}, % changed
    xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.5,
    ymax=3,ymin=-1, % changed
    % the following three lines are an ugly hack to get lines at top and bottom, there are probably better ways
    extra y ticks={-1,3},
    extra y tick labels={},
    extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},
    minor tick num=1, % added
    ylabel={$f_{(t)}$}, xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel style={above},  % changed
    xlabel style={right}, % changed
    ticklabel style={fill=black!20,circle,inner sep=1pt}, % added
    % the following three lines to get square grid
    scale only axis,
    width=8cm,
    height=4cm
    ]

    % changed from draw to addplot
    \addplot [ultra thick,blue] coordinates {(0,0)(1,2)(1,0)(2,0)};
    \addplot [ultra thick,blue,dashed] coordinates {(2,0)(3,2)(3,0)(4,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!